# How to display image in imageButton as background only after being pressed?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I want to know if there is a way to make an imagebutton display its image after it is pressed.

I need this to be done in my *Java main Activity, not in the XML layout file*.

The button should be blank white in beginning and *when pressed I want it to display its image.* The method I am in gets passed a View from the button, if you need to know that.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: with out code we can not guess what you are doing but I think there could be two possible reasons of it 
1) Image is too bulky <i mean it is huge in size , make sure you have compressed it >
2) ImageButton not getting validate , so validate it after setting image .
3) are Yew setting Image resource or background?

Answer (score 0):

To add image programmatically when pressed  you need to do this :

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn); imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_img_drawable); } });
```

And in xml no need to use

```
android:src=" "
```

Do let me know if this was helpful

Comment: i ended up just having to use these 2 lines

`code` ImageButton v = (ImageButton) findViewById(view.getId());
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluex); `code`